# PayPal IPN on Refund - Does it send the 'note to buyer' back to my server?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to make the 'note to buyer' (which was entered on PayPal's site when a refund was made) available to the vendor and buyer on my own website (which links multiple buyers and vendors in a reverse auction system).

I am receiving IPN notifications of the refund, but not it seems the 'note to buyer'.

Is there a way to obtain this information?

Or do I need to implement a refunding system on my own system in order to get the 'reason'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran a test refund on my sandbox account and I can confirm that the IPN does not include the "Note to buyer" data filled in on the PayPal refund screen.

I also tested the RefundTransaction API to see if the Note parameter there would come back in IPN and that does not either.